# Selecting specific worker for connection

Tags: perl, hypnotoad

So, I'm using a hypnotoad server for my application and is trying to maintain state for connections. Turns out for every connection a different worker is spawned/selected. Can I somehow make this selection explicit? Also is there a way to know which worker was used for my last request and use it again for corresponding requests?

Comment: Are you talking about regular HTTP requests, or Web Sockets? Have you tried issuing HTTP headers for keep-alive connections?

Comment: @simbabque I'm talking about regular HTTP requests. The thing is I have an endpoint where another server communicates, over which I don't have any control, that's the reason I can't keep-alive a connection.

Comment: Don't, solve your problem a different way.

Answer (score -1):

You can ran multiple masters (every with one worker or like morbo - single processes).

And add load balancer before 'em which will be responsible to selection of concrete process per connection.

Typically I used **nginx** with upstream module [`sticky` setting](https://nginx.ru/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#sticky).

Comment: Well that's the last option.